# Route Parameter Value Always 0 in ASP.NET Core 1.x

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I found a strange behaviour while developing an ASP.NET Core 1.x Web API app. Here's a code snippet

```
[Route("{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get(string id)
{
  ...
}
```

If I send a request to the API endpoint like `/api/values/1234` it works OK. Now, I change the parameter type from `string` to `int` like:

```
[Route("{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
  ...
}
```

If I send the same request `/api/values/1234`, the `id` value is always `0`, which is not supposed to be.

I tried `{id:int}` as well, it doesn't work either. I also tried `[HttpGet("{id}")]` and `[HttpGet("{id:int}")]` instead of using `[Route("{id}")]`. But none of them is working as expected.

I'm sure this worked fine on ASP.NET Core RC1 and RC2. However, it doesn't work on ASP.NET Core 1.x as expected. What am I missing?

---

**UPDATE**:

Found that my actual implementation required `long` value, not `int` value. After I changed the parameter type to `long`, it worked as expected.

Comment: Both `[HttpGet("{id}")]` and `[Route("{id}")] [HttpGet]` should work fine. Check if there's some conflicting routes. I've created a new project and I was able to get the Id with no problems.

Comment: +1 to conflicting routes. If you create new project using yoman tool (yo aspnet -> select Web API Application) you will find the generated ValuesController that do exactly what you want using [HttpGet("{id}")]

Comment: I found that the number used in my actual development was `long` value, not `int` value. All good. Thanks!